# How to change language for an application from masterpage using ressource files in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an appplication in ASP.Net with C#.
In the masterpage in aspx file I have 3 image buttons with 3 languages: english, french, romanian:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImgRo" ImageUrl="~/Images/Romania Flag.png" runat="server" 
                 Height="25px" ToolTip="RO" style="border-color:black; 
                 background-color:black" OnClick="ImgRo_CLick"/>|
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImgEn" ImageUrl="~/Images/United States Flag.png" runat="server" 
                 Height="25px" ToolTip="EN" style="border-color:black; 
                 background-color:black" OnClick="ImgEn_CLick"/>|
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImgFr" ImageUrl="~/Images/France Flag.png" runat="server" 
                 Height="25px" ToolTip="FR" style="border-color:black; 
                 background-color:black" OnClick="ImgFr_CLick"/>|
```

When I click one of each I have events to save chosen language on session :

```
protected void ImgRo_CLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveLanguage("Ro");
}
protected void ImgEn_CLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveLanguage("En");
}
protected void ImgFr_CLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveLanguage("fr-Fr");
}

protected void SaveLanguage(string language)
{
    Session[AppDefs.LANGUAGE] = language;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
}

public string GetLanguage()
{

    if (Session[AppDefs.LANGUAGE] != null)
    {
        return Session[AppDefs.LANGUAGE].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "en";
    }
}
```

In the master page I open login page and then other pages. How can I change UICulture for all pages when I choose from master page ?

I try in login page on preinit event this, but doesn't work:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UICulture = Master.GetLanguage();//"fr-FR"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Storing the culture name in a session variable is a good start, but you have to change the threading cultures in CurrentThread for each request. Try the following code in PreInit:

```
var language = Master.GetLanguage();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
```

Comment: The problem is that application goes first in login page - preinit event and then it go on "ImgFr_CLick" , button event

Comment: You can't set the UICulture for a page, just for a page's request. This setting won't last between requests. You have to refresh it in each new request. The preferred location for this refresh is the PreInit event of your page. If your page and your login page have localizable text, both need a PreInit with the code I provided.